# How to manage an empty jQuery object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code:

**PHP CODE**:

```
if($data2_array[7]['status'] == "OK"){
        $degtorad = 0.01745329; 
        $radtodeg = 57.29577951; 

        $dlong = ($lng - $supermercado_lng); 
        $dvalue = (sin($lat * $degtorad) * sin($supermercado_lat * $degtorad)) 
        + (cos($lat * $degtorad) * cos($supermercado_lat * $degtorad) 
        * cos($dlong * $degtorad)); 

        $dd = acos($dvalue) * $radtodeg; 

        $dist_supermercado_millas = ($dd * 69.16);  
        $dist_supermercado_km = ($dd * 111.302); 
        $dist_supermercado_metros = round(($dist_supermercado_km * 1000),0);
    }else{
        $dist_supermercado_metros = "";
    }
```

**JS CODE**:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
                data : {direccion : direccion}
            }).done(function(data){
                var sitios = data.split(',');
                    jQuery("#ff_elem245").val(sitios[7]);
});
```

If the variable `$dist_supermercado_metros` returns empty from the PHP, the ajax shows `""` inside the text field. How can I do in the ajax so that the value returned is empty instead of `""`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not `HTML`.... you could check for `data` length. If the length is not good don't `.split()` it and don't update the `input value`

Comment: @Spokey lol your right, it was PHP XD

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a conditional that checks if the data is not empty, and have the code execute only in that case

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
                data : {direccion : direccion},
            }).done(function(data){
                if (data) {
                   var sitios = data.split(',');
                   jQuery("#ff_elem245").val(sitios[7]);
                }
});
```

or if you need to reset the input value you can do

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
                data : {direccion : direccion},
            }).done(function(data){
                if (!data) {
                   jQuery("#ff_elem245").val('');
                } else {
                   var sitios = data.split(',');
                   jQuery("#ff_elem245").val(sitios[7]);
                }
});
```